# How to take $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{(x^2+x+1)^2}$?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

The integral is really easy but I am stuck on some steps:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{(x^2+x+1)^2}$$

As it is improper integral with both upper and lower infinity limits I've rewritten it like:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{dx}{(x^2+x+1)^2} + \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{(x^2+x+1)^2}$$

So the solutions should be the same with differences in limits afterwards.

Take the first one and complete the square:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{dx}{(x^2+x+1)^2}$$ = $$\int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{dx}{\left((x+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}\right)^2}$$ 
What's the best way to proceed here? I was thinking of $$t = x +\frac{1}{2}$$

But it does not seem to be the most logical.

Comment: In general: completing the square is almost always profitable when dealing with quadratics in integrals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, when you substitute $\text{u}=x+\frac{1}{2}$:

$$\mathscr{I}:=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{\left(x^2+x+1\right)^2}\space\text{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{\left(\text{u}^2+\frac{3}{4}\right)^2}\space\text{d}\text{u}\tag1$$

Now, substitute $\text{s}=\arctan\left(\frac{2\cdot\text{u}}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$:

$$\mathscr{I}=\frac{8}{3\sqrt{3}}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^\frac{\pi}{2}\cos^2\left(\text{s}\right)\space\text{d}\text{s}\tag2$$